# jQuery fadeout not working

Tags: jquery, css, fadeout

Okay, so I have this code:

```
$('#login').click(function() {
        $('#main').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $(this).html($('#hidden-login-div').html()).fadeIn('fast');
        });
    });
```

On this page:  http://ag.kirindesigns.com/search.php

I want it to fadeout the main division (with ID of "main") when you click the login button in the upper left (with ID of "login").  However, the code you see isn't doing anything.

If you click the Search button, however, the main div will fade out...using almost exactly the same code, here's the code the search button is using (which is part of an ajax call).

```
 $('#main').fadeOut('slow', function() {
      $(this).html(data).fadeIn('fast');
      height = $('#main').height();
      frame.height(height + 40);
      frame.width("720");
  });
```

I attempted to use the .slideUp() option just to see what happens.  The bottom of the division flickers, like it's trying to slide up but acts like it hits a wall and just jumps and then does nothing.  So I'm a tad confused on what's causing this issue and why it works perfectly fine in the ajax call but won't work on a simple .click() call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```
$('#login').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#main').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).html($('#hidden-login-div').html()).fadeIn('fast');
    });
});
```

Comment: _why_ do you believe this is the answer? _how_ does it work? Simply telling someone to _change their code_ without any context or meaning does not help them learn what they did wrong, and is also not useful for future readers.

Comment: Gah!  I feel totally stupid, I should have known to preventDefault.  Thanks so much for pointing out that error of mine!  I appreciate all of your help!

Comment: Actually it was very useful.  I totally forgot to prevent the default action of the A tag.  His answer was spot on perfect in pointing that out.  I imagine other readers who forgot the same will learn from it just fine.

Comment: Oh ok dear  GrumpyCrouton, but i think it force them to search about preventDefault, but yeah, you are right